# How to make flex children align to the middle?

Tags: css

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

Currently, the parent has a display of `flex`, and it's relevant code is:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

with the children having the code of:

```
flex: 0 0 100%;
```

In a different project I made it work by giving the parent a display of `table` and the children a display of `table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`. However, using table to position elements isn't a good practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the right direction?

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: Would this for the children or the parent?

Comment: Just added it to the parent and it's all working. Thanks!